# How can I prevent a gap that appears between menu items?

Tags: html, css

There is a gap that appears when I try to make menu using the following code on Firefox 3.6
Its works fine in IE 8.  Can some one please suggest a workaround?

```
<html>
<title>Menu</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Faculty</span></li>
        <li><span>Students</span></li>
        <li><span>CCE Configuration</span></li>
        <li><span>Curriculum</span></li>
        <li><span>Prepare Reports</span></li>
        <li><span>Help</span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

with the following CSS

```
li
{
display:inline;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding: 0;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're displaying them inline, and you probably have whitespace between the elements, which gets condensed to a single space in the rendered HTML.

Use `display: block; float: left;` instead of `display: inline;`.

Comment: @coreyward If you set `float:left`, the element becomes a block automatically and `display:block` is not needed.

Comment: @Šime: cool, did not know that!  Are we able to count on that across all browsers?

Comment: But there is another problem..The menu does not start from extreme left..there appears to be a gap on the left..how I do get this to start from the extreme left...?

Comment: are you using `html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }` ?

Comment: No..If I put any text before the menu in html then we can see that the menu start from a bit left like it is indented..

Comment: @JMC Yes, it's specified here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo If float has a value other than "none", display:inline becomes display:block

Comment: Your <ul> is probably still indented by the default browser styles. Use `ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to get rid of it.

Comment: @Vinay Consider using a CSS reset stylesheet (e.g. Yahoo CSS Reset)

Comment: @Vinay: you may want to consider using a reset stylesheet. http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: Ah hell @Šime, you beat me by seconds.

Comment: @Vinay You probably want to use a reset stylesheet http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ (I couldn't help myself after seeing it twice already :). It's a good idea to use one to help you get projects done without as many issues until you learn about all the quirks and stuff.